# Getting base64 img src and email it

Tags: php, email, base64

I am creating a JPEG image and trying to send it via email. But the problem is the file i am trying to send come with a error

> Could not access file

This function is under postergenerator.php

```
function returnImage() {
        ob_start();
        header( "Content-type: image/jpeg" );
        imagejpeg( $my_img,null,100);
        imagecolordeallocate( $line_color );
        imagecolordeallocate( $text_color );
        imagecolordeallocate( $background );
        imagedestroy( $my_img );
        $i = ob_get_clean();
        echo base64_encode( $i ); 
        return base64_encode( $i );
    }
```

This script is to get the image base64 and send it to mail SendEmail.php

```
$formdata = array();
foreach($_POST as $key => $value )
{
$formdata[$key] = $value;
}
$formdata["resize"] = 1;

include "postergenerator.php";
//returnImage();

require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer(); // create a new object
$mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 465; // or 587
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username = "***@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "****";
$mail->SetFrom("***@gmail.com");
$mail->Subject = "Test";
$mail->Body = "hello";
$mail->AddAddress("***@msn.com");

$file_to_attach = returnImage();

$mail->AddAttachment($file_to_attach);

if(!$mail ->Send())
{
    echo 'mailer error:' . $mail->Errorinfo;

}
else
{

echo "Mail has been sent";
}
```

When I run the SendEmail.php script the output is:

```
 <img  src='data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j ****I deleted it***** class="img-responsive">
```

> ```
> Could not access file: 
> Mail has been sent
> ```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
$mail->addAttachment(..)
```

Only allows you to add file attachments from your **local file system**.
Your

```
returnImage()
```

function returns a base64 encoded **string**.

In your case, I'd do something similar to this:

```
$mail->Body = sprintf("<img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,%s' alt='' />", returnImage());
```